# How to make scrolling clouds with Flash, jQuery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

Is it possible to make scrolling clouds with Flash, jQuery or JavaScript? If yes, could you please give me code, that I would need to insert in homepage?

I got 3 small cloud images, and I need to make them move on the background, they should be under content, but over body, for example I got content (margin: 0 auto; (in middle) where text is located e.c.), and body image (sky and grass on the ground), the clouds should fly horizontally, is that possible to make?

Comment: Yes; what've you tried, and what went wrong? Where are you stuck? Also, jQuery is JavaScript.

Comment: it is possible, but rather than just asking for the code, perhaps you should try looking into the jQuery animate function http://api.jquery.com/animate/  You will also need to use the css z-index property so the clouds don't appear over the content. I think people are much more willing to help if you can demonstrate where you have tried to figure it out rather than asking for someone to do all the work for you for free.

Comment: you can achieve it with either JavaScript or Flash, you should really attempt to put something together yourself first for people to then help you with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. This demo show the result you're looking for: [jQuery scrolling background](http://www.queness.com/resources/html/bgscroll/index.html) If you want to go through the tutorial you can read it here: [Create Background Scrolling Effect with jQuery](http://www.queness.com/post/2607/create-background-scrolling-effect-with-jquery)